# What is the benefit of assigning a variable of a Mapper Instance to be static?

Tags: java, spring, mapstruct, mapper

Let's suppose I have a Mapper Interface as follows:

```
public interface SomeMapper {
     SomeMapper INSTANCE = Mappers.getMapper(SomeMapper.class);


     //Some Random Method
     public RandomResponse doSomething();
}
```

And then I have an Executor Class which uses the Mapper:

```
public class someExecutor {
     private final SomeMapper someMapper = SomeMapper.INSTANCE;

     public void someFunction() {
     final randomVariable = someMapper.doSomething();
     }
}
```

I want to understand if there's any benefit to making the someMapper variable inside someExecutor class as static. So example would be:

```
private static final SomeMapper someMapper = SomeMapper.INSTANCE;
```

Is there a benefit of assigning it as static vs assigning it as just private final?

Comment: Just as an aside: instead of defining instances, we can use `@Mapper(componentModel = MappingConstants.ComponentModel.SPRING)` to register a mapper as bean. This makes the corresponding mapper injectable, and we do not need to create instances manually (and have additional testability due to DI).

Comment: Why do you need a duplicate variable altogether?

Answer (score 0):

There could be, but I doubt it would be measurable unless you are mapping 100K objects, and measuring performance. I my guess is that it does not matter.
By having a static instance, you could be saving some memory (if there is state), but unless you are converting a lot, I doubt you could measure the difference when the JVM is up and running.